# Command "npm run build" exited with 1 in Versel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am developing a next.js app using MapBox and firebase.
Works fine on localHost but its not getting deployed.

Building
46s
Cloning github.com/Aindrail/CAB_APP (Branch: main, Commit: 34cf9dc)
Cloning completed: 246.128ms
Installing build runtime...
Build runtime installed: 2.486s
No Build Cache available
Installing dependencies...
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
added 425 packages in 13s
78 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
Detected Next.js version: 12.1.0
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
Running "npm run build"

> cab_app@0.1.0 build
> next build
> Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
> This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
> You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
> https://nextjs.org/telemetry
> info  - Checking validity of types...
> ./pages/index.js
> 33:3  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> 54:16  Warning: passHref is missing. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
> ./pages/login.js
> 27:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
> info  - Creating an optimized production build...
> info  - Compiled successfully
> info  - Collecting page data...
> Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in
> pages/data/carList
> See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should run `npm run build` locally before deploying. And properly check your error log, that's already mentioned `found page without a React Component as default export in pages/data/carList`
You used a component without default export. Check cartList properply. Hopefully, it will be fixed.

Comment: export const carList = [
  {
    imgUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cyvcpfF/uberx.png',
    service: 'UberX',
    multiplier: 1,
  },
  {
    imgUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/YDYMKny/uberxl.png',
    service: 'UberXL',
    multiplier: 1.5,
  },
  {
    imgUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/Xx4G91m/uberblack.png',
    service: 'Black',
    multiplier: 2,
  },
  {
    imgUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cyvcpfF/uberx.png',
    service: 'Comfort',
    multiplier: 1.2,
  },
  {
    imgUrl: ' https://i.ibb.co/1nStPWT/uberblacksuv.png',
    service: 'Black SUV',
    multiplier: 2.8,
  }
]

Comment: my carList file cointains this only. It was provided by default in the data list from where i did this project.